# Get last part of the link

Tags: php, regex, parsing, hyperlink

We have a link like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281910/h1-and-semantic-html5`

How do I get the part, which is before the last and after last but one `/`?

**In this example we would get** `h1-and-semantic-html5`

**More examples:**

From the link `http://dribbble.com/highlights/2012/` we get `2012`

From `http://www.apple.com/iphone/` we get `iphone`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Last Part of URL PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`basename` should provide what you're looking for:

```
php > echo basename("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281910/h1-and-semantic-html5");
h1-and-semantic-html5

php > echo basename("http://dribbble.com/highlights/2012/");
2012

php > echo basename("http://www.apple.com/iphone/");
iphone
```

Read more about it in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

Comment: You might want to use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to get the *path* part of the URL, then use `basename()` on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fin = preg_replace('#.*/([^/]+)/?$#', '$1', $whole);
```

Grab the last portion of non-forward slash characters (potentially followed by a forward slash)